# Kong API Gateway

Tags: kong

We are currently studying about kong API gateway.

We know about Kongs API authentication and all the other things. We do not know how to implement it in php.

How we can insert and retrieve data from database and return it through the Kong API gateway.

And if you have any demo than provide us so we can easily understand.

Answer (score 5):

Kong is API Gateway server and it does not matter which language your APIs are created in. You have to install kong first using different ways provided [here](https://getkong.org/install/).

Once Kong is running you can use [Kong Admin APIs](https://getkong.org/docs/0.11.x/admin-api/) to add your developed APIs to kong. Once APIs are on-boarded to Kong they are available for consume.

Answer (score 0):

You just expose your API as usual, than you can setup the service and route in the Kong API Gateway to point to your PHP endpoint.

Basically Kong just proxy the client request to your endpoint and get the response, than return back to the requester. At the same time, you may apply certain checking and filtering at Kong to enhance your security and features.